# perl regex to print all the occurences of the matched pattern from the occurence of word "xxx" till the occurence of word "yyy"

Tags: regex, perl

file has

```
sub TC1
{

check(CLEANUP_SUB=>\&cleanup1);
check(CLEANUP_SUB=>\&cleanup2);
check(CLEANUP_SUB=>\&cleanup3);
endcase
}

sub TC2
{
check(CLEANUP_SUB=>\&cleanup4);
check(CLEANUP_SUB=>\&cleanup5);
check(CLEANUP_SUB=>\&cleanup6);
endcase();
}
```

### Expected output

```
\&cleanup1
\&cleanup2
\&cleanup3
```

I want all the pattern after /sub TC1/ till first occurrence of /endcase/

```
perl -0777 -ne 'if(/sub\sTC1/){while(/CLEANUP_SUB\s*=>([^),;]+)/g){print "$&\n";}}' file
```

### Output

```
\&cleanup1
\&cleanup2
\&cleanup3
\&cleanup4
\&cleanup5
\&cleanup6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the flip-flop operator (`..`).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

while (<>) {
  if (/sub TC1/ .. /endcase/) {
    /CLEANUP_SUB\s*=>([^),;]+)/ and say $1;
  }
}
```

Or (as a one-liner):

```
$ perl -nE '/sub TC1/ .. /endcase/ and /CLEANUP_SUB\s*=>([^),;]+)/ and say $1' file
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. But I also wants to match the word after  if it begins with "sub"  CLEANUP_SUB => sub xyz ------> it should print xyz in this case

Comment: @Sasi: If you have further requirements, then you should ask a new question.